# custom html code in a repeater

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I'd have a repeater with some group logic inside. Basically, on the ItemDataBound method, I show or hide some controls inside the item.

But I've a problem, I want to add a header group template (and footer) : < ul> and < /ul>

For example, the following code :

```
<ul id="UlControl" runat="server"><asp:Label id (....) </ul> 

and then (in the databound method)

UlControl.Visible = false;
```

Result : All the html code inside < ul> / < /ul> will be hidden.

I tryied to put a  and inside an html < ul> but asp .net will auto close the < ul>.

I think about a placeholder but is it possible to add some code without validation ?

Regards

Comment: How about doing the `.Visible=` only on the part that you want to hide which I assume is inside the <ul> ?

Comment: Why don't you just set the visibility in the code-behind? Why does it have to happen whilst data-binding?

Comment: Is this any use to you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736415/how-can-i-create-a-custom-repeater-that-displays-header-footer-based-on-properti